# From where can I install Report Application Server?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reporting

I need RAS installed in my machine in order to create dynamic reports with the RAS SDK in .NET. I don't know how to install it. In which version of Crystal Report Server is it available?

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227482%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) RAS is available in Crystal Reports 10 and up.

And from [another MSDN page on RAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225325%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> **Using the RAS API without a RAS server**
>
> In Crystal Reports, you can access the advanced report creation and
>   modification functionality of the ReportClientDocument Object Model
>   (RAS) from the CR .NET SDK. The deployment package in this scenario
>   requires only the .NET assemblies, meaning you are using the RAS API
>   in-process.
>
> However, if you use the RAS API in-process, you lose the performance
>   and stability benefits of a server-oriented, out-process system. To
>   gain these benefits, use the RAS API in conjunction with a RAS Server
>   in a Crystal Reports Server or BusinessObjects Enterprise environment.
>
> For additional information and sample code, see the
>   ReportClientDocument property of the
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument class in the API
>   reference.